# how to enable image editor in self-hosted cloud9 c9sdk?

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide

How do I enable the image editor in the self-hosted c9sdk?

[image: image editor greyed out c9sdk]

https://github.com/c9/core

I've looked through the c9 package lists and it's not there

Answer (score 1):

The image editor becomes available when you open an image. Double click on an image in the tree to see it open in the image editor (the image viewer only opens for .gif files).

Comment: On the self-hosts C9SDK? Mine open as text/binary files